# Is there a way to make a responsive Zurb Foundation 6 menu that uses click or tap on desktop, rather than hover?

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I've been searching the web for a while now trying to find documentation or an example of a responsive menu built in Zurb Foundation 6 that uses clicks rather than hovers on desktop. I see in the documentation that there were ways to do it in Foundation 5. But I can't find anything for 6. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! the plugins on this page https://get.foundation/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html#js-options explain that you can use "data-disable-hover" and "data-click-open". I have used them in conjunction to get a dropdown menu to work as a click menu.